# Append Data MySQL Query Two Tables

Tags: php, mysql, append

I have two tables: **product** and **url_alias**

**product** table has two columns: **product_id** and **model**

**url_alias** table has two columns: **product_id** and **keyword**

So, product_id is **unique** & **primary key** for both tables.

Now, I want to add (append) info of **product.model** to **url_alias.keyword** if **product_id** of both tables is same.

For example:

```
product.product_id = 123
product.model = 987

product.product_id = 123
url_alias.keyword = my-first-book.html

Desired result = 987-my-first-book.html
```

How can I do it?

PS: `'-'` hyphen is also required to add with model.

Comment: where is php in the above?

Answer (score 0):

Try `CONCAT`::

```
Select
product.product_id,
CONCAT(product.model,'-', url_alias.keyword)
from 
product 
inner join url_alias on (url_alias.product_id=product.product_id)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT CONCAT(product.model, '-', url_alias.keyword) AS url
FROM product
INNER JOIN url_alias
ON product.product_id = url_alias.product_id
WHERE product.product_id = '123'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    SELECT CONCAT(p.product_id,' - ',u.keyword ) AS res
    FROM product AS p
    LEFT JOIN
    url_alias AS u USING (product_id)
    WHERE p.product_id = 123
```

Note : Remove the WHERE condition if you want  to get result for all the products